# speed up a 2-3hour rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got this rake task on rails that populates my database, It needs to run daily.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
namespace :tm do
  task reload: :environment do
    gzipped = open('csv link')
    csv_text = Zlib::GzipReader.new(gzipped).read
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)

    csv.each do |row|
      if row[4] == 'logo url'
      else
      tmdate = Date.parse(row[10]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      viatmdate = Date.parse(row[10]).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
      swtmdate = row[10]
      tmlocation = row[6].split('at ')[1]
      place = row[11].split('|')[1]
      place1 = row[11].split('|')[2]
      place2 = row[11].split('|')[3]
      location = '' + place + ', ' + place1 + ', ' + place2 + ''
      tmtime = row[9]
      text = row[7].gsub('text', '')
      if text.include? '&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD'
        eventname = text.gsub('&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD', 'e')
      else
        eventname = text.gsub(/[ªÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüÿ]/, '')
      end

      if text.include? '&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD'
        tmname = text.gsub('&#xFFFD;&#xFFFD', 'e')
      else
        tmname = text.gsub(/[ªÀÈÌÒÙàèìòùÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúÂÊÎÔÛâêîôûÃÑÕãñõÄËÏÖÜŸäëïöüÿ]/, '')
    end
    if text.include? ' -'
      tmnamesplit = text.split(' -')[0]
    end
    if tmname[/[^0-9]/].present?
      tmnamenn = tmname.gsub(/[^0-9]/i, '')
    end
        text2urldb = text2.where('eventtitle ILIKE ? AND eventdoortime = ? ', "%#{tmname.gsub(/[\-\:\ ]/, '%')}%", tmdate.to_s).first
        text3urldb = text3.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time = ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{tmname}%", tmtime.to_s, tmdate.to_s).first

        text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? AND promotional_text = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s, "%#{place}%").first

        if tmnamesplit.present?
          if text1urldb.blank?
            text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ?', "%#{tmnamesplit}%", viatmdate.to_s).first
          end
          if text3urldb.blank?
            text3urldb = text3.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND delivery_time = ? AND valid_from = ?', "%#{tmnamesplit}%", tmtime.to_s, tmdate.to_s).first
          end
        end

        if text1urldb.blank?
          text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? AND promotional_text = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s, "%#{location}%").first
          if text1urldb.blank?
            text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s).first
          end
          if text1urldb.blank?
            text1urldb = text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? AND promotional_text = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s, "%#{tmlocation}%").first
          end
        end



      if text1urldb.present?
        vurl = text1urldb.merchant_deep_link
        txt = vurl
        re1 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
        re2 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
        re3 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
        re4 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
        re5 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
        re6 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
        re7 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
        re8 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)' # Uninteresting: word
        re9 = '.*?' # Non-greedy match on filler
        re10 = '(?:[a-z][a-z]+)'    # Uninteresting: word
        re11 = '.*?'    # Non-greedy match on filler
        re12 = '((?:[a-z][a-z]+))'  # Word 1
        re = (re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6 + re7 + re8 + re9 + re10 + re11 + re12)
        m = Regexp.new(re, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
        if m.match(txt)
          word1 = m.match(txt)[1]
        end
      end


      gmiurl = text3urldb.merchant_deep_link if text3urldb.present?

      gigurl = text2urldb.eventurl if text2urldb.present?

      api = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('text url' + tmname + '&when_from=' + swtmdate)).parsed_response
      api1 = api['Paging']
      api2 = api1['TotalResultCount']

      if api1.blank?
        newapi = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('texturl' + tmnamenn + '&when_from=' + swtmdate)).parsed_response
        paging = newapi['Paging']
        api2 = paging['TotalResultCount']
        if newapi.blank?
          apisplit = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('texturl' + tmnamesplit + '&when_from=' + swtmdate)).parsed_response
          pagingsplit = apisplit['Paging']
          api2 = pagingsplit['TotalResultCount']
        end
      end
      text1 = vurl
      text3 = gmiurl
      text2 = gigurl

      if api2 == 0
      else
        swurl = api['Events'].first['SwURL']
      end
      event = Event.find_by(time: row[9], date: row[10], eventname: eventname, eventvenuename: location)

      if event.present?
        event.update(event_type: word1, text: row[8], eventimage: row[4], textlink: swurl, text1link: text1, text3url: text3, text2url: text2)
      else
        Event.create(time: row[9], date: row[10], event_type: word1, text: row[8], eventimage: row[4], eventname: eventname, eventvenuename: location, textlink: swurl, text1link: text1, text3url: text3, text2url: text2)
      end

    end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I'm willing to do anything, The csv link is an api link to a csv. I'm willing to split this up over multiple files, The issues it i have no idea how long it takes to run, So it'd have to be a once complete run next rake task.

At the moment, This takes around 2-3 hours to complete and populate the db.

Any ideas how to speed this up?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: Where does the CSV come from? Is it possible to generate it in a way that does not need to many changes when importing? You do some API request. Is it possible to get rid of them, can you do them async on in bulk?

Comment: `text1.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? AND promotional_text = ?', "%#{tmname}%", viatmdate.to_s, "%#{location}%").first.to_sql` run this to see an actual output of the query. Maybe next use `EXPLAIN` to see if you have setup properly your database indexes. Give us the output so people can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

You can :
- Use background's jobs for recurrent task like this.  (For example : sidekiq)
- Ensure you DB indexes are properly set.

To get more responses on this problem :
- Use rails naming convention for your variables
- Clean your code, some assignment's makes it unreadable
- Use methods to do some redundant stuffs

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for replying, 

I havent got indexes on any db table, Not sure how to go about this. I'm using heroku scheduler to make this run everyday. Would sidekiq be better than this?

Comment: Sidekiq will use a worker dyno. So it will be executed in parallele than your web server.

Comment: For indexes, create a migration like `bundle exec rails generate migration add_missing_indexes`.
You will have a new migration file where you will be able to add in `def change` :
`add_index :table_name, :column_name`

Answer (score 0):

Add database indexes. You are doing quite a few queries there and the columns `productname`, `specifications`, `eventtitle` etc. should all be considered to have indexes.

Comment: Hi there,

Productname and eventtitle are not unique, Can they have indexes?

Comment: I don't know what database you use but neither Postgres, MySQL or Mongodb require indexes to be unique.

Comment: specifications eventtitle productname etc are coming from the csv? how would i index these?

Comment: The CSV file can't be indexed at all and isn't the cause of your speed problem.